# .env file works for existing keys, but new ones I add are undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, environment-variables, vue-cli, dotenv

I have inherited a Vue app which uses axios. In the dataService.js, it grabs urls from a project `.env` file with `process.env.FOO_BAR` for get calls.

The key value pairs that existed already, like `VUE_APP_DATA_URL` work fine, but if I add a new one like `SOME_NEW_KEY` or `VUE_SOME_NEW_KEY` it logs as undefined with `process.env.SOME_NEW_KEY` in the dataService.js file where the old / existing ones log fine.

I've restarted the app, but not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: they must start with "VUE_APP_", e.g. `VUE_APP_SOME_NEW_KEY`

Answer (score 1):

This is a DevSecOps feature provided by vue.js. This ensures that you do not expose any sensitive environment variables accidentally to the front-end or client.

Any variables you want to be accessible client side must start with `VUE_APP_`. You can still use keys without `VUE_APP_`, however, they will be available only to node.js environment on server side (if you have any code running there).